# is there anyway to fuse 2d lidar readings and camera reading in ros

Tags: lidar, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am using a 2d lidar tilted at an angle such that it hits the ground and we are also using a mono-cam for detection of objects (static etc) . Is there any way that i can fuse these two reading i.e the lidar readings onto the camera readings so that i can measure the dist of object through this fuse data(width and x,y positions of the boundaries)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237415/is-there-anyway-to-fuse-2d-lidar-readings-and-camera-reading-in-ros/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

your answer is [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/99211/how-to-combine-a-camera-image-and-a-laser-pointcloud-to-create-a-color-pointcloud/).

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2016-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0